# Rotated image in Mapbox are skewed

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I have a dji photo that I want to place at the exact coordinates in Mapbox.
But when I rotate the image It become skewed.
I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43891269/rotated-points-in-mapbox-are-skewed) that I solve is problem but didn't work for me.

```
calculateCoordinatesCorner(altitude, coordinates, rotation) {

    // Caractéristique de la caméra du drone.
    const Ray = 6371
    const Kilometers = (Math.PI * Ray) / 180
    const radius = 78
    const radians = (Math.PI / 180) * rotation 

    // Calcul en mètre terreste de la demi longueur et de la demi hauteur.
    const distanceBetwenCenterLat = altitude * Math.tan((radius / 2) * Math.PI / 180) / 1000 
    const distanceBetwenCenterLong = altitude * Math.tan((radius / 2) * Math.PI / 180)  / 1000 

    // Calcul des des coordonnées gps en degrés des 4 coints de l'image.
    let latUp = coordinates[0] + (distanceBetwenCenterLat / Kilometers)

    let latDown = coordinates[0] - (distanceBetwenCenterLat / Kilometers)

    let longUp = coordinates[1] + (distanceBetwenCenterLong / (Kilometers * Math.cos(coordinates[0])))

    let longDown = coordinates[1] - (distanceBetwenCenterLong / (Kilometers * Math.cos(coordinates[0])))

    let midCoordinates = [

        [latUp, longUp],
        [latDown, longUp],
        [latDown, longDown],
        [latUp, longDown]
    ]

    console.log(midCoordinates)

    // Rotation de l'image.
    function rotate(lat, long) {
        let  newMidCoordinates = []
        newMidCoordinates = ll2Mercator(coordinates[0], coordinates[1])
        
        let nlat = (Math.cos(radians) * (lat - newMidCoordinates[0])) + (-Math.sin(radians) * (long - newMidCoordinates[1])) + newMidCoordinates[0]
        let nlong = (Math.cos(radians) * (long - newMidCoordinates[1])) + (Math.sin(radians) * (lat - newMidCoordinates[0])) + newMidCoordinates[1]

        return [nlat, nlong]

    }

    function ll2Mercator(lat, lon) {
        let rMajor = 6378137 //Equatorial Radius, WGS84
        let shift = Math.PI * rMajor
        let x = lon * shift / 180
        let y = Math.log(Math.tan((90 + lat) * Math.PI / 360)) / (Math.PI / 180)
        y = y * shift / 180

        return [y, x]
    }

    let UTMCoordinates = []
    for (let i = 0; i < midCoordinates.length; i++)
        UTMCoordinates[i] = ll2Mercator(midCoordinates[i][0], midCoordinates[i][1])

        console.log(UTMCoordinates)

    let rotateCoordinates = []
    for (let i = 0; i < UTMCoordinates.length; i++)
        rotateCoordinates[i] = rotate(UTMCoordinates[i][0], UTMCoordinates[i][1])

        console.log(rotateCoordinates)

    function Mercator2ll(mercY, mercX) {
        let rMajor = 6378137 //Equatorial Radius, WGS84
        let shift = Math.PI * rMajor
        let lon = mercX / shift * 180
        let lat = mercY / shift * 180
        lat = 180 / Math.PI * (2 * Math.atan(Math.exp(lat * Math.PI / 180)) - Math.PI / 2)

        return [lat, lon]
    }

    let finalCoordinates = []
    for (let i = 0; i < rotateCoordinates.length; i++)
        finalCoordinates[i] = Mercator2ll(rotateCoordinates[i][0], rotateCoordinates[i][1])

    console.log(finalCoordinates)

    return finalCoordinates


}
```

This is the image before the rotation :
[image]

And ths is the image after the rotation [image]

I don't think I made any mistakes in the formula.
What is wrong?

Here the code to add the image on the map :

```
    let c2 = new Coordinates(99.80, [6.8517520041548465, 48.54234199589907], 108.5)
let CornerCoordinates = c2.calculateCoordinatesCorner(c2.altitude, c2.coordinates, c2.rotation)

map.on('load', () => {

    map.addSource('radar1', {
        'type': 'image',
        'url': 'https://i.ibb.co/djNk9Kw/default.jpg',
        'coordinates': CornerCoordinates


    });
    map.addLayer({
        id: 'radar-layer1',
        'type': 'raster',
        'source': 'radar1',
        'paint': {
            'raster-fade-duration': 0,
            'raster-opacity': 0.5

        }

    });
```

Comment: How do you display your image? Please edit your question and add that part of the code.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I just edited the question rn @TomazicM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say there's no sense in reinventing wheel. Why bother with formulas prone to error, when you can use some existing library like [turf.js](https://turfjs.org/) and its method `turf.transformRotate` (see https://turfjs.org/docs/#transformRotate).

Since I'm not familiar with your coordinate manipulating methods, I'll assume `CornerCoordinates` start in lower left corner and go counter clockwise.

Coordinates rotation code could then look something like this:

```
var coords = [
  [-80.425, 46.437],
  [-71.516, 46.437],
  [-71.516, 37.936],
  [-80.425, 37.936]
];
var rotationAngle = 15;   // in degrees

var bbox = [coords[0][0], coords[0][1], coords[2][0], coords[2][1]];
var bboxPolygon = turf.bboxPolygon(bbox);
var rotatedPolygon = turf.transformRotate(bboxPolygon, rotationAngle);

var rotatedCoords = (turf.getcoords(rotatedPolygon))[0].slice(0, 4);
```

Comment: Thank you, it work fine right now.